# Not getting Live data from Aviationstack api

Tags: null, response

i am using following endpoint to get response from API using paid version:
https://api.aviationstack.com/v1/flights?access_key=fi324rkjn32e2e44%20flight_status=active

also tried this:
https://api.aviationstack.com/v1/flights?access_key=fi324rkjn32e2e44

but I am getting null in "live" and "aircraft":

```
{
  "pagination": {
    "limit": 100,
    "offset": 0,
    "count": 100,
    "total": 454057
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "flight_date": "2024-03-30",
      "flight_status": "active",
      "departure": {
        "airport": "King Khaled International",
        "timezone": "Asia/Riyadh",
        "iata": "RUH",
        "icao": "OERK",
        "terminal": "T4",
        "gate": null,
        "delay": 11,
        "scheduled": "2024-03-30T09:55:00+00:00",
        "estimated": "2024-03-30T09:55:00+00:00",
        "actual": "2024-03-30T10:05:00+00:00",
        "estimated_runway": "2024-03-30T10:05:00+00:00",
        "actual_runway": "2024-03-30T10:05:00+00:00"
      },
      "arrival": {
        "airport": "Istanbul Airport",
        "timezone": "Europe/Istanbul",
        "iata": "IST",
        "icao": "LTFM",
        "terminal": "1",
        "gate": null,
        "baggage": "25",
        "delay": null,
        "scheduled": "2024-03-30T14:50:00+00:00",
        "estimated": "2024-03-30T14:50:00+00:00",
        "actual": null,
        "estimated_runway": null,
        "actual_runway": null
      },
      "airline": {
        "name": "Aeroflot",
        "iata": "SU",
        "icao": "AFL"
      },
      "flight": {
        "number": "4115",
        "iata": "SU4115",
        "icao": "AFL4115",
        "codeshared": {
          "airline_name": "saudia",
          "airline_iata": "sv",
          "airline_icao": "sva",
          "flight_number": "263",
          "flight_iata": "sv263",
          "flight_icao": "sva263"
        }
      },
      "aircraft": null,
      "live": null
    }
```

I tried to fetch api and get its live data, but not getting it. I am expecting to get lat long in live section as they told in their documentation